# Why does the default CarrierWave uploader's `filename` method have a condition on original_filename?

Tags: carrierwave

I would like to understand why the [default CarrierWave uploader](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/e7bdabb1160160fa4dbb4566b6240399a86ab310/lib/generators/templates/uploader.rb#L48) has the condition `if original_filename`.

```
# Override the filename of the uploaded files:
# Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
def filename
    "something.jpg" if original_filename
end
```

Why isn't it just:

```
def filename
    "something.jpg"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check in details the source code, but if you don't specify this condition, carrierwave will somehow always consider that the image "exists" even there is none (ie if it's not on the filesystem).

So your "non existing image" will have a url, and the default_url will never be used (=> 404 on these images)